# Cache control: why does the universally used meta tag not affect my cache control?

Tags: html, caching, meta-tags, image-gallery, cache-control

I'm currently developing an **online gallery** which allows a customer to view their photographed images and order different products of each (e.g. prints, canvasses, mugs, etc). My problem is that to go through each image, they must choose from a list of images at the top of the page, which redirects them to their image. But this is only a **local redirect** (e.g. index.php?image=8, index.php?image=14 etc) so it **caches the image, causing each page re-load to have the same image**, but stretched to the new image's dimension.

I figured this was a **cache problem**, so I took to stackoverflow to find a solution, and came across the suggestion to use this meta tag, amongst others:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

Unfortunately, it still seems to be caching my images (in opera, internet explorer, but not chrome)

Why would my browser not be picking this tag up? Or does it not do what I am expecting it to do.. Thanks for your time everybody!

Comment: It would really help if we could see an example but perhaps you also need to send the Cache-control header along with the image file when it is sent by the server.  The meta tag will only prevent the caching of the HTML page, not the image itself.

Comment: If you use something like FiddlerTool and look at the responses on the individual images you'll be able to see the caching policy that is being applied.... that might give you a pointer as to where you need to investigate. Worst case scenario would be to add a random cachebuster parameter to each image